# How to prove that matrix multiplication of two 2x2 matrices can't be done in less than 7 multiplications?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, lower-bounds

In Strassen's matrix multiplication, we state one strange ( at least to me) fact that matrix multiplication of two 2 x 2 takes 7 multiplication.

**Question :** How to prove that it is impossible to multiply two 2 x 2 matrices in 6 multiplications?

Please note that matrices are over integers.

Comment: There are other matrix multiplication algorithms that can be faster. This web article from a Stanford CME 323 class provides details about Strassen's algorithm, [Matrix multiplication: Strassen's algorithm](https://stanford.edu/~rezab/classes/cme323/S16/notes/Lecture03/cme323_lec3.pdf). There is a Wikipedia topic, [Strassen algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) that goes into details and has links to additional information.

Comment: @RichardChambers Notice that Strassen’s algorithm has $7$ multiplications. It seems plausible to me that this lower bound is true.

Comment: As worded this question is wrong. There are plenty of matrices that can be multiplied with $6$ multiplications. You mean to ask for a proof that, in the worst case, it takes 7 aka there exists some matrix that requires 7

Comment: @StellaBiderman yes I saw that Strassen's has 7 multiplications. I did not look at the other, faster and algorithms with a lower complexity. From what I can tell they use the same sub-matrix approach as Strassen's but I am not sure. I was just adding some additional information about Strassen's specifically.

Comment: There seems to be something missing from your question. I can easily give an algorithm which can multiply at least some matrices with 0 multiplications. There's probably a constraint that you are not mentioning.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a classical result of Winograd: [On multiplication of 2x2 matrices](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379571900097).

Strassen showed that the exponent of matrix multiplication is the same as the exponent of the tensor rank of matrix multiplication tensors: the algebraic complexity of $n\times n$ matrix multiplication is $O(n^\alpha)$ iff the tensor rank of $\langle n,n,n \rangle$ (the matrix multiplication tensor corresponding to the multiplication of two $n\times n$ matrices) is $O(n^\alpha)$. Strassen's algorithm uses the easy direction to deduce an $O(n^{\log_27})$ from the upper bound $R(\langle 2,2,2 \rangle) \leq 7$.

Winograd's result implies that $R(\langle 2,2,2 \rangle)=7$. [Landsberg](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0407224) showed that the border rank of $\langle 2,2,2 \rangle$ is also 7, and [Bläser et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.09652) recently extended that to support rank and border support rank. Border rank and support rank are weaker (=smaller) notions of rank that have been used (in the case of border rank) or proposed (in the case of support rank) in the fast matrix multiplication algorithms.

Answer (score 7):

You can find the result at:

S.Winograd, *On multiplication of 2×2
matrices*, Linear Algebra and Appl. 4 (1971), 381–388, MR0297115 (45:6173).